# How to create dynamic child table with DAX in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have this table:

```
Order | Total  | FirstPayment | Months
1     | 1000   | 2021-01-01   | 2
2     | 600    | 2021-02-01   | 3
```

And I need to create a another table with the installments, like this:

```
Month      | Order  | Value
2021-01-01 | 1      | 500
2021-02-01 | 1      | 500
2021-02-01 | 2      | 200
2021-03-01 | 2      | 200
2021-04-01 | 2      | 200
```

So, I want to create a child table with one row for each month of payment.

Please, can you help?

Comment: I would actually create table with all dates between your first and last installments for all orders and then create measure that would show values just for relevant dates.

Comment: Thanks W.B. It would solve part of the problem. But I need to display the installments records. :/

Comment: And you can do that. The trick is to use SUMX on the date table and for each date check and calculate installments for all orders that fall due on that date.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, I would actually do it like this:

Create dates table that spans all dates between two ranges. You could actually filter it to contain only relevant dates for better performance, but I didn't bother (this is a table formula):

```
Payments = CALENDAR(MIN(Orders[FirstPayment]), MAXX(Orders, EDATE(Orders[FirstPayment], Orders[Months])))
```

Create a measure that would show appropriate values for relevant dates:

```
Payment amount = 
SUMX (
    Payments,
    VAR d =
        DAY ( Payments[Date] )
    RETURN
        SUMX (
            FILTER (
                Orders,
                DAY ( Orders[FirstPayment] )
                    == d
                        && Payments[Date] <= EDATE ( Orders[FirstPayment], Orders[Months] -1 )
                        && Payments[Date] >= Orders[FirstPayment]
            ),
            [Total] / [Months]
        )
)
```

The result - based on Order from Orders table and Date from Payments table:

[image]

**EDIT**

Of course, it is also possible to do what you asked. You have to combine the two formulas to create a calculated table like this (below is a table formula that you apply when you select New table):

```
Installments =
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    FILTER (
        CROSSJOIN (
            CALENDAR (
                MIN ( Orders[FirstPayment] ),
                MAXX ( Orders, EDATE ( Orders[FirstPayment], Orders[Months] ) )
            ),
            Orders
        ),
        [Date] >= [FirstPayment]
            && DAY ( [Date] ) = DAY ( [FirstPayment] )
            && [Date]
                <= EDATE ( [FirstPayment], [Months] - 1 )
    ),
    "Date", [Date],
    "Order", [Order],
    "Value", [Total] / [Months]
)
```

[image]

Comment: It worked gracefully. Thank you very much!